# Neo4j and Mongodb as datasource in Grails

Tags: grails-orm, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-mongodb, distributed-transactions, distributed-database

I am using spring-data-neo4j in my Grails application because of limited functionality of neo4j gorm (neo4j plugin) . I am planning to use Neo4j and Mongodb both as my datasource . Is there any way that I could map a single Domain in both neo4j and Mongodb (Grails core provides facility of using multiple database)

http://www.grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/conf.html#dataSource